# editing a file using cpp code without creating a new file

Tags: c++, file

Is it possible to edit text in a file using cpp code. Already there is related question on it, but it doesn't solve my problem. Kindly help me out.
I have given a rough code line on this.
seek() through the file and try to replace the contents with new string from that point till the end of line.
I need the "hello" string be placed and must be the end of line.

like if we have new.txt as

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST

If I want the file content to be changed as

ABCDEHELLO

I am getting the file content as

ABCDHELLOJKLMNOPQRST

```
fstream file("new.txt",fstream::in|fstream::out);
file.open();
while(getline(file,str))
{
  if(value==strstr())
  {
    file.seekp(pos);
    str.erase(pos,len);//len specifies the value till end of str
    str.replace(pos,6,"hello");
    char *d=new char[str.length()+1];
    strcpy(d,str.c_str());
    file.write(d,strlen(d));
    delete [] d;

  }
}
```

If I could copy the file contents to the string, manipulate it, then copy to the new file then it is possible.

Is it possible to change the contents in the same file. If so kindly help me out, I am struck in this. If the replacing string is longer than the one actually existing then this works, but if the replacing string is smaller than the one which is actually existing then I am unable to do.

Comment: why not string instead of char?

Comment: Accessing it as string, but for write() alone it is sent in char *

Comment: But, you are using file streams. I don't mind the mix in C++ and C, but if I se C++... I use C++.

Comment: Can give another example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can overwrite bytes in an existing file, as you are doing, but what you can't (directly) do is shift the remaining bytes in the file forward or backward e.g. to accommodate a longer or shorter string in the middle of the file.  If you want to 'delete' or 'insert' bytes from/into the middle of a file, the only way to do it is to read the remainder of the file's contents into memory, truncate the file, and then write the remaining data back out to disk again.  In most cases it's easier just to read the entire file into RAM, modify the data in RAM, then write it all out again.

Answer (score 0):

if you case is only one line in the file you can easily separate the I/O process in two stages. Read the file and get the position of the text. then close the file and reopened as out then write the string you want. Note that this will work if you have one line in the file
check the following code

```
std::string value = "GFGHHFGHH";
std::string str;
std::fstream file("new.txt", std::ios::in);
std::size_t found;
while (file >> str)
{
    found = str.find(value);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.erase(value.length() );
        str.replace(found, 6, "hello");
    }
}
file.close();
file.open("new.txt", std::ios::out);
file << str;
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using system call for sed:

```
string s="sed -i s/hey/ho/g file0102.txt";
system(s.c_str());
```